# Translate messages using ajax form to login

Tags: ajax, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using symfony 3.2 and I'd like to login with ajax form. Everything works fine except messages are not translated.

this is the AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler class

```
class AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
/**
 * @var mixed
 */
private $translator;

/**
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils        $httpUtils
 * @param array                                             $options
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                          $logger
 * @param mixed                                             $translator
 */
public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel, HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, LoggerInterface $logger = null, $translator = null)
{
    parent::__construct($httpKernel, $httpUtils, $options, $logger);

    $this->translator = $translator;
}

/**
* {@inheritDoc}
*/
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new Response(json_encode(array(
            'has_error' => true,
            'message'     => $this->translator->trans($exception->getMessage())
        )));
    }

    return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
}
```

**Solution for symfony 4:**

For symfony 4 we can do like this:

```
'message' => $this->translator->trans($exception->getMessageKey(), array(), 'security'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your translation line to this:

```
$this->translator->trans($exception->getMessage(), array(), 'messages')
```

then create translation file in your Resources/translations folder for each language i.e. messages.en.yml, messages.fr.yml, etc...

your $exception->getMessage() should try and return translation keys to simplify things so for example it should return "error.name.missing" and then in the yml translation file you'd have:

```
error.name.missing: 'The name cannot be missing'
```